# Does energy intake before training influence motor skills and concentration?

Tags: diet, energy

I was playing table tennis with an empty stomach today and I wasn't concentrated and my game lacked accuracy. Is there a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure there is a correlation. Whenever you are participating in any physical activity from a 5k to table tennis, energy for your body is a must. Even though table tennis isn't the most demanding sport, it still requires a lot of energy for your body to maintain its ability and focus. The energy gained from food helps you keep your mind sharp and your body fueled, so there definitely is a link there.